# Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver : bound method WebElement.click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm new to python. I tried to extract data on https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/?path=details&symbol=SILVER#login by giving user name and password. It works.
But when try to hit on another button it doesn't work. ('Deposite' or the 'X' to close)

HTML of the Deposit element:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Deposit</button>
```

Snapshot of the Deposit element:

[image]

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Chromedriver\\Chromedriver.exe")

driver.maximize_window();
driver.get('https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/?path=details&symbol=SILVER#login')

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div[1]/input").send_keys("username@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div[2]/input").send_keys("password_here")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/button").click()
time.sleep(20) # wait for loading
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/button").click()
```

output is

```
<bound method WebElement.click of <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="28205c2be15699403ddfcc3f3ce2fa33", element="03ae577c-b3d4-423c-b7ed-1d9c5ea3ea1a")>>
```

Can you please help me to solve this (or a different approach) and go forward to scrape some text from the website.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add the relevant HTML of the element you are trying to click.

Comment: Not the screenshot of the element, but the relevant HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click on the element with text as **Deposit** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and text()='Deposit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I tried both answers after following

'from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

But following msg comes

`NameError: name 'By' is not defined`

I.m new and confused in how to use it. Please help again

Comment: You missed the import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`